# how to empty value on unchecking checkbox in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs. I have created below code to make checkbox and to get value of checkbox. But on unchecking the checkbox I'm still getting the value. How to remove value of unchecking the checkbox. Please help.

below is in html

```
<input onChange={(event)=>this.getCheckboxValue(event)} type='checkbox' value={item.title}/>
```

Below is function

```
 getCheckboxValue(event) {
   console.log(event.target.value)
 }
```

Comment: but also I need to get the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the checkbox doesn't change. You're interested in whether it's checked (`event.target.checked`) in addition to its value (`event.target.value`).

```
<input onChange={this.onChange} type='checkbox' value={item.title}/>
```

```js
onChange = (event) => {
  const {checked, value} = event.target;
  if (checked) {
    // do something with value
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes..got it..but also I need to get the value of checked element

Comment: @SagarKodte what do you mean get the value? Can you be more specific?

Comment: there is value={item.title} I need to get this when checked and if unchecked it should be blank

Comment: I have done  this.setState({checked:value})
      console.log(this.state.checked) this.but on first checked m getting empty